# PyQt5 Pixmap from Built in Cursor

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I need to retrieve a cursor's pixmap in order to set a drag and drop action's default cursor.

```
drag = QtGui.QDrag(event.widget())
curs = QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeHorCursor)
drag.setDragCursor(curs.pixmap()) # curs.pixmap() is returning a 0x0 pixmap
```

Calls like self.setCursor(curs) work just fine on widgets, properly displaying the cursor when I hover over them. However, like I said, PyQt seems to be messing up converting a valid cursor into a pixmap.

Is there a quick fix for this, or will I have to just use my own cursor images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html#pixmap) seems to be working exactly as documented:

> QPixmap QCursor::pixmap() const
>
> Returns the cursor pixmap. This is only valid if the cursor is a
>   pixmap cursor.

That is, it will only return a pixmap if you explicitly set one in the constructor (and the same goes for bitmaps).

Comment: Ah, the tricks they play! Thanks, but does QT have a nice way to access the directory where the system default cursors are?

Comment: @ZackAllen. You could look at the Qt sources to see how QCursor does it. My hunch is that each plaform will have a very different way of doing things. X11 has the freedesktop specs, but there's nothing equivalent Windows and OSX.